# Scan worksheet for missing items per ID

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with IDs of people visiting on certain days.

Simple example.
[image: example]

I want to scan all IDs to check if they have missed a visit day. When visit day 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are obligated.

I can't add code to this database, because it is locked (it is a worksheet with confidential info).

I don't know where to start.

Comment: This can be done using excel formulas if that's an option for you? If you are not the owner of the workbook and there are other users, you may not be able to convert it to xlsm if it is not already one.

Comment: The excel file is an xlsx right now. I don't know about the formulas you are mentioning. But if it works it works, if an VBA script would be better then I can ask the creator to implement it. Cause it would save me (and colleagues) a lot of time by just doing this manually, where I filter a subject ID and see which days they visited and which are missing. But there are lots of ID's, so imagine the time spent on this.

Comment: So what would be the expected output (and in what structure) based on the example you provided?

Comment: Well, an output telling me which subject id is missing which visit day.
In an external sheet or some other output, I don't really know all possibilities. As long as I can have a clear view of the subject id and the missing days, that would be great.
And thank you for helping me! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that not all days are obligated. Say, day 1, 2,3,4,5,10,14 are obligated. All other days are extra. What I mean is that I need to know if the subject has visited all those days, and if one of those days is missing, I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is using **Power Query** which is available in Excel 2010 Professional Plus and all later versions of Excel. My demonstration is using **Excel 365**.

Suppose you have two tables:

- Table1 is called **Tbl_Visitday** which is the 2-Column table in your example;
- Table2 is called **Rng_Obligated** which is a 1-Column table containing all obligated days.

[image: Tables]

1. Go to `Data` tab in your Excel ribbon, use **From Table** function to add both tables to the power query editor one by one. When you access the editor for the first time, make sure set up the `Query Options` as below to avoid loading every query to a new worksheet;

[image: Query Option]

2. Once you have added both tables to the editor, make a duplicate of `Tbl_Visitday` in the `Queries` section on the left hand side as shown below:

[image: Queries]

3. Let's work on `Rng_Obligated` first, highlight the column, use **Transpose** function under the `Transform` tab to transpose the data from rows to columns, then use **Merge Columns** function to merge all columns by delimiter semicolon `;`, then you should have something like the following:

[image: Tbl_Obligated]

4. Let's move to `Tbl_Obligated(2)`, remove the `Visitday` column, remove duplicates within the `ID` column and sort it ascending, then you should have:

[image: Sorted]

5. Use **Append Queries** function under the `Home` tab to append `Rng_Obligated` table to the current table, and then right click the `Merged` column header and choose **Fill -> Up** to quickly fill the merged column with the same string, then you should have something like follow:

[image: Append]

6. Filtered the `ID` column to hide `null`, then use the **Split Columns** function under the `Transform` tab to split the `Merged` column by delimiter semicolon `;`, and in the advanced options to choose to put the results into **Rows** as shown below:

[image: Splited]

7. Use **Merge Queries** function under the `Home` tab to merge `Tbl_Visitday` table with the current table by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and select the first and second column consecutively in each table as shown below:

[image: Merged]

8. Expand the newly merge column to show `Visitday` column only, add a **custom column** using this formula `=[Merged]=[Visitday]`, then filter the `Custom` column to show `FALSE` results only, then you should have:

[image: Filtered]

9. Change the format of the `Merged` column to `Text`, then use **Group By** function under the `Transform` tab to group the `Merged` column by `ID` as shown below, the result will be `error` which is expected:

[image: Group By]

10. Go back to the last step in the **APPLIED STEPS** section on the right hand side, go to the formula bar and replace this part of the formula `List.Sum([Merged])` with `Text.Combine([Merged],",")`, hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and you will notice the `error` have become a text string as shown below:

[image: Result]

11. You can close and load the query which will be created as a connection if you have amended the query setting in the first step. You can click **Queries & Connections** under the `Data` tab and right click the query and choose to load it to a specific location in your workbook.

> In your case, you will need to ask the owner of the shared workbook to unlock the workbook so you can use the power query editor and load the output. Alternatively you can copy and paste the data to a new workbook where you can execute the power query to obtain the result.
>
> Power Query allows you to update your source tables and recalculate the output (once you  choose to refresh the data) in the back-end normally in a few seconds. If you do not want the output to be refreshed, you can copy and paste the output to a new table so the results stay unchanged.

Here are the power query **M Code** for the two tables for your reference. Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

**Rng_Obligated**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Rng_Obligated"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"obligated", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transposed Table", {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}}, "en-AU"),{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

**Tbl_Visitday(2)**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tbl_Visitday"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Visitday", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Visitday"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Sorted Rows", Rng_Obligated}),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Appended Query",{"Merged"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Up", each ([ID] <> null)),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows", {{"Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Merged"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Merged", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type1",{"ID", "Merged"},Tbl_Visitday,{"ID", "Visitday"},"Table6",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table6" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table6", {"Visitday"}, {"Visitday"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table6", "Custom", each [Merged]=[Visitday]),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = false)),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Merged", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type2", {"ID"}, {{"MissedDay", each Text.Combine([Merged],","), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm gonna take a look at it tomorrow and I will let you know if I have any problems or not.

Comment: I took a quick look and I seem to be missing the Power Query addon in our Excel 2013. I would have to ask IT to install it. I hope this is possible.
If I can't get Power Query, is there a different way of achieving the same results?

Comment: Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. If you are dealing with a large data set (say over thousands of records), then you will need either `power query` or `vba` for this task, otherwise it can also be done using formula.

Comment: I read that article yesterday, that's how I figured that I needed to install it :)
And yes, there are like 1000-2000 records. Sometimes less. 
Well, I'm going to ask about that Power Query. But I have a hard feeling about it.

Comment: Well, I asked IT and it isn't possible right now or near future. But since VBA is always possible, how hard is it to set that up?

Comment: @Bokkoman you can add `#vba` to the tags of your post so other contributors may be able to assist. I am not a `#vba` expert :)

Comment: Alright, I did. Thanks for all your help. I'll still try and get that Power Query running here, it seems very helpful, even for other things.